# Reason for "L.Control.Draw is not a constructor" error?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Leaflet Map</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.2.3/leaflet.draw.css" />
        <script type='application/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.2.3/leaflet.draw.js'</script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style=" position:absolute; top:50; bottom:10; width:99.9%; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; height: 100%; "></div>

        <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"></script>

        <script>
            var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
            mapLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
            L.tileLayer(
                'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
                maxZoom: 18,
            }).addTo(map);

            var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();

            map.addLayer(editableLayers);

            var drawPluginOptions = {
                position: 'topright',
                draw: {
                    polygon: {
                        allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
                        drawError: {
                            color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
                            message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
                        },

                        shapeOptions: {
                           color: '#97009c'
                        }
                    },
                    // disable toolbar item by setting it to false
                    polyline: false,
                    circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
                    rectangle: false,
                    marker: false,
                },
                edit: {
                    featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
                    remove: false
                }
             };
             var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(drawPluginOptions);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error and also `L is not defined` error is coming while adding `leaflet.draw.js`.

Comment: At the eighth line there is not "Greater than" character (>).

Comment: And how are you adding `leaflet.draw.js`???

Answer (score 1):

Add script of leaflet draw after `body` tag. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`leaflet.draw` (and any Leaflet extension) should be added after `<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"></script>` in `head` or `body` tag.