# How to use Draw.js in a Leaflet offline map

Tags: offline, leaflet-draw

I'm trying to build a data-collecting map using Leaflet. To do this I have to download the Leaflet JavaScript files but I can't find out how to download a working draw.js.

When I download draw.js I get this error

```
index.html:138 Uncaught TypeError: L.Control.Draw is not a constructor
```

I'm using this code for the map variable

```
var map = L.map('map', {drawControl: true, center: [42.381899, -71.122499], zoom: 13});
```

and in my code block

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  draw : {
    polygon : false,
    polyline : false,
    rectangle : false,
    circle : false
  },
  edit : false,
  remove: false
});
```

Comment: [@Jan-Eric](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/83326/jan-eric), have you seen this article [TypeError: L.Control.Draw is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930066/typeerror-l-control-draw-is-not-a-constructor). Probably a duplicate of [Why I getting L.Control.Draw is not a constructor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232880/why-i-getting-l-control-draw-is-not-a-constructor).

Comment: [@Jan-Eric](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/83326/jan-eric) what happens if you place this line `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>` in the head tag instead of the body tag?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example, that is your full HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you download all of the js, css, and image files associated with Leaflet Draw. All of the files are available at  https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw